# Configuring an external harddisk for Linux

Tags: linux, hard-disk, cp

I've purchased a new external hard disk for using in Linux and I have two questions: one about the permissions and other about copying data. Here are them:

1. I've formatted the disk using GParted (I've created two partitions, one in ext4, and a small one in FAT32). But I can't access the ext4 partition from my user as after the creation with GParted the owner is root. As I can see in the web I can change the owner and group as `chown -R username:username /media/username/nameofdrive`. After that I can write in the disk. But my question is: does this mean that I can acces to the disk only from my computer with my username? If I plug the hard disk in another computer with Linux but with different username, could I write in it?
2. The first step with the disk is copying all the information I have in my old disk (formatted in ext3, but configured not by me, so this is the reason why I'm asking this questions). I would like to make the copy using the `cp` command. Is it enough a command like

```
cp -R /media/username/disk_old/folder/ /media/username/disk_new/
```

or are necessary more options as

```
cp -aR /media/username/disk_old/folder/ /media/username/disk_new/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are almost right, but it is not your *username* but the numeric *uid*.  So if you are user *1000* on your computer, create a file on the disk, and transfer it to another computer, it will belong to whoever has uid *1000* on that computer.
2. `cp -R` copies recursively, but resets timestamps, ownerships and such.  `cp -aR` preserves all this (but all copied files will belong to you, unless you are root).
   (Please ask a different question for a different topic).